# How can I populate an Asp.net dropdown using a sqldatasource which has the connectionstring bound at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

So, I've been fighting with this for more time than I'd like to admit, and can't seem to find info on what I'm doing wrong.  So, humbly, I submit this question.

I have 2 dropdowns and datasources as defined here:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddAdminYear" runat="server" enabled="false"      DataTextField="YEAR_ID" DataValueField="YEAR_ID" AutoPostBack="True" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
<asp:ListItem Text="----------" Value="----------" /></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsAdminDistinctYr" runat="server"
ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT YEAR_ID FROM  PC_YEAR ORDER BY YEAR_ID" DataSourceMode="DataReader"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:DropDownList ID="tbOneUnit" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 

DataTextField="LONG_DESC" DataValueField="SHORT_DESC_EN" AppendDataBoundItems="True" Enabled="True">
    <asp:ListItem Text="----------" Value="----------" /></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsAdminMunic" runat="server" Onselecting="eventselect" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="GET_MUNIC_LISTING_VB" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" >
<SelectParameters> 
      <asp:controlparameter DefaultValue="2017"     Name="year" controlid="ddAdminYear" propertyname="SelectedValue"/>
      <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="default"  Name="region" Type="String"/>
      <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="default"  Name="u_r" Type="String"/>
      <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="default"  Name="UserGroup" Type="String"/>
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The connectionString for sdsAdminDistinctYr is set when the page loads.  The code that runs looks like this:

```
sdsAdminDistinctYr.ConnectionString = _user.SelectedDBConn
ddAdminYear.DataSourceID = "sdsAdminDistinctYr"
```

Then, in the select event handler for ddAdminYear, I set the datasource for tbOneUnit as follows:

```
sdsAdminMunic.ConnectionString = _user.SelectedDBConn
tbOneUnit.DataSourceID = "sdsAdminMunic"
tbOneUnit.DataBind()
```

The ddAdminYear dropdown populates, however, the tbOneUnit dropdown does not.

How can I get the tbOneUnit dropdown to populate using a stored procedure based on the ddAdminYear value?

EDIT:
I can't post the stored procedure itself, but here's the header:

```
[dbo].[GET_MUNIC_LISTING_VB] (
    @YEAR smallint,
    @REGION as varchar(5) = NULL,
    @U_R as varchar(2) = NULL, 
    @USERGROUP as varchar(10) = NULL)
```

I can verify it returns data.
Let me know if anything else would be helpful.

Edit #2:
   The stored procedure is running, but the "default" values are being passed as strings (which I had specified)... So, that's not what I want to do.
Right now the application will pass something like :

```
exec GET_MUNIC_LISTING_VB @year=N'2017',@region=N'default,N'@u_r=N'default',@UserGroup=N'default'
```

To the application, whereas I'd like it to pass:
exec GET_MUNIC_LISTING_VB @year=N'2017',@region=default,@u_r=default,@UserGroup=default

Comment: Could you show `GET_MUNIC_LISTING_VB` store procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like my issue is that I was specifying parameters for executing a stored procedure, when I wanted to use the defaults defined in the stored procedure.

I was able to fix this by commenting out the parameters I had specified, leaving only the ddAdminYear controlParameter.  This produced the following code RPC:

```
exec GET_MUNIC_LISTING_VB @year=N'2017'
```

Thanks to everyone who posted, and put in an effort.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem one of two ways depending on how much data you will need for all possible combinations of data for the two drop downs.

If you have a limited number of values for ddAdminYear I would create a tbOneUnit for each value, then I would dynamically show or hide each of these drop downs based on the selected value using some javascript. You would need to create a foreach loop and unique Id or some other identifier so that you could identify each unique drop down.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ddAdminYear').change(function() {

        var adminYear = $(this).val();

        $('.tbOneUnit').hide();
        $('#tbOneUnit_' + adminYear).show();

    });
});
```

If you have too much data for solution above, then another solution would be to create an ajax event every time the ddAdminYear changed, and use that to populate the data for tbOneUnit. This of course would require you to write a method on from the server that would return the correct data for tbOneUnit based on the current value of ddAdminYear.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ddAdminYear').change(function() {

        var adminYear = $(this).val();

        var get = $.ajax('/GetTbData', adminYear);

        get.done(function(data) {
            // take data and add to drop down here
        });

    });
});
```